# Discord.js code: 50001, status: 403, method: 'put'

Tags: discord.js

I'm building a bot with Discord.js.
I wrote below code, and persists same error.
How can I fix or avoid that error?

```js
require("dotenv").config();
const fs = require("fs");
const { REST } = require("@discordjs/rest");
const { Routes } = require("discord-api-types/v9");
const commands = [];
const commandfiles = fs.readdirSync("./src/Commands").filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));

commandfiles.forEach(commandfile => {
    const command = require(`./Commands/${commandfile}`);
    commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
});

const restClient = new REST({version: "9"}).setToken(process.env.TOKEN);

restClient.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(process.env.DISCORD_APPLICATION_ID, process.env.DISCORD_GUILD_ID),
{body: commands})
.then(()=> console.log("Successfully registered commands"))
.catch(console.error);
```

Error message and stacktrace:

```
DiscordAPIError[50001]: Missing Access
    at SequentialHandler.runRequest (C:\Users\kitel\vscode workspace\DiscordBot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:708:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (C:\Users\kitel\vscode workspace\DiscordBot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:511:14) {
  rawError: { message: 'Missing Access', code: 50001 },
  code: 50001,
  status: 403,
  method: 'put',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v9/applications/932218396219674624/guilds/932240564102000710/commands',
  requestBody: { files: undefined, json: [ [Object] ] }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> { rawError: { message: 'Missing Access', code: 50001 }

As you mentioned, it's missing access i think. Enable your intents on web and grant your bot application commands privilege.